# Salary, detaining and interrogating

Tags: papers-please

I have a few closely related questions regarding interrogating and detaining, and their effect on how much money you can make.

Does salary depend on anything except the number of immigrants passing through your booth (ignoring the ones which incured penalties), and doesn't really care about whether or not they pass? Is the exact formula simply the number of immigrants times 5? (In particular, is it prudent to try and detain someone as opposed to just turning him back to save time and process more immigrants?)

Is there any point in interrogating immigrants in the first days, before you can detain them, or is it just a waste of time?

If not, is there any point interrogating them about things that won't get them detained, like an expired passport, as opposed to simply denying them (until the point when you have to stamp the reason for denial, at least)? Especially in cases of discrepancies between what they say and what their entry permit says. They always weasel out of it and there seems to be no point talking to them, at least as far as money is concerned.

Comment: You might want to split them into separate questions as they don't seem to be directly related. THe fact that this question contains multiple sub-questions also makes the question title next to useless...

Comment: From my experience - Time = money. The more time you have, the more money you can accumulate. Detaining takes precious seconds, so don't detain anyone until the guard comes and strikes a deal with you. Even then - the first few times, he won't pay up. Haven't tested what he says when you don't detain someone. So: If you see a discrepancy and don't have to stamp the reason, deny them outright.

Comment: @deutschZuid: They all are more or less the same question: should I stop them or not, the specific formulations only reflect the fact that the conditions change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salary is based on the people that pass your booth and as far as I know it's 5 × customers served.

While it's safe to immediately dismiss the red sweater guy with the crayon drawn passports, this is not true in general. Sometimes people won't produce papers until asked to. Often people will 180° when confronted with speech intent violations.

It is faster to dismiss than to detain, so in general you want to avoid going crazy with the jail time. However, one you unlock detaining-based bribes, the detain button becomes an investment - in the time two people are detained you might be able to make one more obvious call like letting a citizen or an ambassador through, but it's tough to do so without risking a citation.

Comment: That said I've only reached day 9 so I'm not sure what kind of complications come up going forward.

Comment: You don't get paid for the people who enter your booth after 6pm. I'm not sure when that happens, exactly.

Comment: @badp there comes a point where the single click to detain is faster than the process of denying and returning their papers.

Comment: @alex it's also not always necessary to highlight discrepancies and interrogate in order to deny a person. You might miss secret token opportunities like this, but if you just stamp denied on a guy with, say, expired/forged/mismatching documents that works too.

Comment: @badp like I said, there comes a point where that doesn't work anymore.